# Take screenshot from background in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iOS application I set a timer that takes screenshot from background ,but it takes screenshot of my application instead of the actual screen of device.
I want screenshot of content that currently displayed on device, how can I do this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a screenshot of the device, when you application is in background, that is not possible.

This is because of Apple Security sandboxing each application.

See the answer here as reference.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548975/1891327

Answer (score 0):

pass the view you want to have as a screenshot

```
- (UIImage *)getScreenShotFromView:(UIView*)view
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
        [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return image;
    }
```