# How to take screenshot of when I open Skype,FB,Twitter , but our app is running background using swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, screenshot, uiaccessibility

how to take screenshot of when I am open Skype, FB or Twitter ,
 but our app is running background using swift .

```
Step 1: Open our app 

Step 2: Move to back ground state ,(press home button)

Step 3: Open third party app like FB,Skype,WhatsApp,Twitter and so on

        (click Skype and open it)

Step 4: Take screen shot of active window like Skype
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: Is it possible to take screenshots while running as a background task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548894/ios-is-it-possible-to-take-screenshots-while-running-as-a-background-task)

Comment: Thanks .  If there is any other way to archive this concept in ios . like  Eg: I have been keep on analysis these below concept , whether it may works in iOS 11 using swift ?could u please explain the process how we can archive these concept in accessibilty.In android they are using accessibilty service class in defaulT. BUT FOR IOS there is no accessibity build in service class ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible on iOS, you can only snapshot your own window/app in code, otherwise the user has to do it using the buttons on their phone.

Comment: Thanks.I have been keep on analysis these below concept , whether it may works in iOS 11 using swift ?

could u please explain the process how we can archive these concept in accessibilty.In android they are using accessibilty service class in defaulT. BUT FOR IOS there is no accessibity build in service class ?

My VoiceoverTestApp(APP name )have to enable voice over and running in background .and I wants to read the text or detect the text or get the text in third party App like Skype ,Email,What APP & so on using swift (iOS iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

you can record screen using replaykit2 as in wwdc session https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/606/

you can try this for your need

Comment: Thanks.I have been keep on analysis these below concept , whether it may works in iOS 11 using swift ?could u please explain the process how we can archive these concept in accessibilty.In android they are using accessibilty service class in defaulT. BUT FOR IOS there is no accessibity build in service class.Enable voiceover & switch to background State After that ,when user open new app like Skype ,Email,What APP ,(third party app).How to know app name and get text of user typed text.e.g. I have open the Skype and typed “hello Apple” . How i can get text “hello Apple”(user typed text)in SWIFT